# Python - Frequency Table Between Unmatched 2 Data Frame with Condition

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I've table contain around 100k unique value with a date and I've another table contain 8M record for the whole year what I need is to count each value from the first table how many times it repeated on the big table during a certain time ( 30 day after the date mentioned in each row)

Table A : Unique Values

| num | time | max |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1110 | 01-11-2022 8:47:00 AM | 01-12-2022 8:47:00 AM |
| 1111 | 02-11-2022 8:47:00 AM | 02-12-2022 8:47:00 AM |
| 1112 | 03-11-2022 8:47:00 AM | 03-12-2022 8:47:00 AM |

Table B : Contain the unique value and duplicated Value

```
num     time
1110    01-11-22 8:47
1110    02-11-22 8:47
1110    03-11-22 8:47
1111    02-11-22 8:47
1111    05-11-22 8:47
1111    06-12-22 8:47
1112    03-11-22 8:47
1112    08-12-22 8:47
1112    09-12-22 8:47
1122    09-12-22 8:47
1123    09-12-22 8:47
1534    09-12-22 8:47
```

i need result as below and later i will need to get the raw data it self
first one include the value im looking for like this

```
num   Count
1110    3
1111    2
1112    1
```

i did the below to extract the unique values first which i need to count later

```
import pandas as pd
    CREATED = pd.read_table(r'C:\Users\Desktop\2022.txt', sep=',',encoding='cp1256',low_memory=False)   
    Jan = CREATED[CREATED.Close_Month == 1]    
    Jan.sort_values(by=['customer','Time'])    
    janu= Jan.drop_duplicates(subset='customer', keep='first')    
    janu.to_csv(r'C:\Users\Desktop\Jan.csv',encoding='cp1256', index=None )
```

i tried the below to count but i dont know how to add the condition for the date gap

1-

```
    janu['count'] = janu['num'].map(CREATED['num'].value_counts())
```

another way

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

A = pd.read_table(r'C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\1.csv',sep=',',encoding='cp1256',low_memory=False)
B = pd.read_table(r'C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\2.csv',sep=',',encoding='cp1256',low_memory=False)

for value in A['num']:
    x = B[B['num'] == value]
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the comments, here is my answer. As I understand, the `num` column is the `user_id`. The `time` is the timestamp of the "first" complaint, and the `max` column is the timestamp of the period we are looking for. The question can be translated to:

> For every `num` in Tables A and B, count the occurrence of `num` that appears in Table B, such that the `time` column satisfies `A.time <= B.time <= A.max`. Fortunately, `A.max` is 30 days from `A.time`

If Table B already *contains* the first complaint (so Table A is a subset of Table B), we can directly use Table B to retrieve what we need. I describe the step-by-step below.

The first one we need to do is to convert the `time` column of B to the `datetime` object, which opens a whole `datetime` library to use.

```py
B['time'] = pd.to_datetime(B['time'], format='%d-%m-%y %I:%M')
```

then we use a combination of `concat` and `groupby` to say that: for every `num`, select only rows that have the `time` value within 30 days of the first `time` occurrence, that is, the min value of `time` for each `num`.

```py
pd.concat([
    df[df['time'] <= df['time'].min() + pd.offsets.Day(30)]
    for _, df in B.groupby('num')
])
```

And we have the answer by using `.value_counts()`. I have the code here to validate the results:

```py
import pandas as pd
B = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ['0001', '01-11-22 8:47'],  # this one satisfies
        ['0001', '02-11-22 8:47'],  # this one satisfies
        ['0001', '01-11-23 8:47'],  # this one does not satisfy
        ['0002', '02-11-22 8:47'],  # this one satisfies
    ],
    columns = ['num', 'time'])

B['time'] = pd.to_datetime(B['time'], format='%d-%m-%y %I:%M')
B_filtered = pd.concat([
    df[df['time'] <= df['time'].min() + pd.offsets.Day(30)]
    for _, df in B.groupby('num')
])
print(B_filtered)
```

it prints:

```
num  time
0001 2022-11-01 08:47:00
0001 2022-11-02 08:47:00
0002 2022-11-02 08:47:00
```

so applying `B_filtered['num'].value_counts()` gives:

```
0001    2
0002    1
```

Comment: its actually more complicated than this, i have a table have some certain customers and the date of their first complain, and another table contain all customers and all complain for the whole year, what i need is to track these certain customer from the table and count how many times they complained over a certain period after their first complain date , lets say customer " 1 " complained for first time on 5 January 2022 i need to know how many times he complained till 5 February 2022 note that he does have many other complains on March and April and else but i don't want those to be counted

Comment: Can you modify the column names in your question so that I can understand more clearly?  I am still a bit confused why Table Two shows "Number" but in the code you used "num".

Comment: done the tables, i need to count the values from table  A which have " time " and " max " how many times they occurred on table B between " time " and " max " period

Comment: iam getting this error for the datetime function " ValueError: time data '01-Nov-22' does not match format '%d-%m-%y %I:%M' (match)
"

Comment: `01-Nov-22` uses the format `'%d-%m-%y'`. If your column uses that format, please change to that. Since I see your question uses `01-11-22 8:47` so I have to use the format `'%d-%m-%y %I:%M'`